# Request запросы python

Tags: python, requests, rabbitmq

Могу ли я сохранить get, post запросы в какой либо вид со всеми заголовками и параметрами? Например строка.
Чтобы он не выполнялся, а передать его в другой сервис, где он уже будет выполнен.
Пытаюсь настроить rabbitmq, сам он выполнять запросы не может, я так понимаю. Поэтому нужно, чтобы передал запрос в виде текста, для дальнейшего запуска

Comment: Воообще любой объект можно сериализовать, в том числе в обычною строку. Библиотека `pickle`, попробуйте в эту сторону покопать

Comment: @ClickName , попробовал ваш совет, тоже самое, все равно сначала выполняется запрос, а в байты преобразоывается ужн результат response 200. Возможно не так что то делаю, но во всяком случае спасибо. Завтра буду пробовать передавать просто данные в формате словаря, а на стороне второго сервиса принимать их для запроса